# javascript form validation phone number

Tags: javascript, validation, phone-number

I thought it would be neat to try to make my own form validation. I'm okay on the code up to testing the phone number. I'm using javascript to only allow numbers, and detect the number of digits. If the digits is 3 or 7, I want to add a dash. It's set at 7 because after i input the first dash, the dash is included in the string, and the second dash become at position 8 in the string. Now that works good, but if the user entered a wrong number and the dash appears, when the user tries to backspace it, it sees that the string length is back to either 3 or or 7 and automatically puts the dash back in there, not allowing the user to go back one space at a time to correct the error. If they hold down backspace, it will delete. I've tried using split and substring and can't figure out how to work it so it works correctly.

HTML

```
<form>
  <input type = 'text' name = 'txtPhone' id = 'txtPhone' onkeypress = 'return numbersOnly(event)' onkeyup = 'validateForm(this.id)'/>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
function numbersOnly(e){
  var unicode = (e.charCode) ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
  if (unicode == 8
   || unicode == 9
   || (unicode >= 48 && unicode <= 57)
  )}
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}

function validateForm(id){
  var id = document.getElementById(id);
  var unicode = (event.charCode) ? event.charCode : event.keyCode;
  // first add slashes after third and sixth digit
  if (id.value.length == 3
   || id.value.length == 7
  ){
    var newValue = id.value += "-";
    id.value = newValue;
  }
  // if backspace is pressed, remove the dash
  if (unicode == 8){
    var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
    value = value.substring(0, value.length - 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you use Jquery in your form?

Comment: easiest way would be to have a variable that records if the last key pressed was a backspace and not add the dash back in again until a different key was pressed. An alternative would be to have a pre-defined template that's visible and track the keystrokes and use that to populate the template via an intermediary string which stores the actual digits (makes you can change template without upsetting the logic eg to support (555)555-5555

Comment: You could use [HTML5 Input Constraint Validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#HTML_Syntax_for_Constraint_Validation) - also, I made some alterations for you http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/A5JpN/1/, lastly in the second function where is 'event' defined? am I missing something with inline functions?

Answer (score 0):

In your `onchange` function, check for a trailing dash *first*. If the field just changed and there's a trailing dash, the user just deleted the following character, and you should delete the dash for them. After you delete the dash, return without doing anything else. Since the `onchange` event won't be fired again until the user changes the field again, your code won't insert another dash because it won't be called again until there are either 6 or 8 characters in the field.

Of course, that's an oversimplification. There are cases where the user could edit the middle of the string and screw things up. I would suggest either a) using a library or b) using a few regular expressions rather than just checking field length.